# Window parent location?

Tags: javascript

We want our window.parent to link to another page on click, how can we go about doing this?

Answer (score 10):

```
window.parent.location.href = 'somePage.html';
```

or in a link:

```
<a href="#" onclick="window.parent.location.href = 'somePage.html';">link</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Following javascript code worked for me

**window.parent.location='somepage.html';**